# how can Windows 7 provide Internet connection?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I connect my Windows 7 to the Internet via USB tethering to my Android.

How can I **connect my Linux box** to the internet.

- the Linux box has only NIC.
- I have a 4 port hub available.

Answer (score 1):

Its clumsy, but you could connect (assuming you have the cables for the hub) the windows computer and the linux box and share the connection from the windows box. I'm am sure there is a better way though.

Comment: I was thinking the same so I came here to ask :-)

Comment: I am sure there is a better way, but that will work (least I can't see why it would not)

Comment: so the next question how win7 provides Inet sharing ....

Comment: go you your connection and click share.

Comment: didn't know it's so easy... thank you

Comment: Its one of the settings, not hard to find.