# how to connect linux to win 7 that tether from my Android?

Tags: tethering, dhcp

not sure if it's an Android question but ...

I connect my win7 to the Inet via USB tethering. I wonder **if and how** I can connect my linux box to the net. It can be done only via ethernet.

Comment: This sounds like a Linux/Windows question rather than an Android one, to be honest. The USB tethering should just be like any other network adapter to the Windows box, I'd imagine. I will say, though, that you'll need a crossover cable (or adapter) to go the ethernet route.

Comment: @Matthew: I think (emphasis on "think" here) that he wants to tether internet to a Win7 machine, then share the internet from the Win7 machine to the Linux machine via an ethernet cable. That's how I read the title, anyhow.

Comment: @eldarerathis is right.... I said I wasn't sure if it was an Android question....

Comment: Which version of Android you have?

Comment: @Pitto: I am on 2.3.3. I created new questions on SU before this one was migrated http://superuser.com/questions/291322/how-can-windows-7-provide-internet-connection My original question was based on hope that I wouldn't have to do "anything" on windows machine....